# How to find if x equals any value in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I currently have an if statement like this:

```
if (x==a||x==b||x==c||x==d||x==e) {
   alert('Hello World!')
};
```

How can I instead test if `x` equals any value in an array such as `[a,b,c,d,e]`?

Thank you!

Comment: Array.indexOf() will do, not all browsers support it but there's a polyfill on mdn.

Answer (score 29):

You can use

```
if([a,b,c,d,e].includes(x)) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if([a,b,c,d,e].indexOf(x) !== -1) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this isn't supported in IE until version nine. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: In general, http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: So what's a way to do it that's supported by IE8?

Comment: Add the shim that is given in the link @DavidThomas provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
<script>
    var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
    var $spans = $("span");
    $spans.eq(0).text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
    $spans.eq(1).text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
    $spans.eq(2).text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));
    $spans.eq(3).text(jQuery.inArray("Pete", arr, 2));
</script>
```

[Read this link for more information about it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this helper function:

```
function in_array(needle,haystack) {
    if( haystack.indexOf) return haystack.indexOf(needle) > -1;
    for( var i=0, l=haystack.length, i<l; i++) if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This makes use of the built-in `indexOf` if available, otherwise it iterates manuatlly.

Comment: It might be better to use ES5 shim for this - that way, once you drop IE8 support, you can remove the shim and the code won't have to change.

Answer (score 0):

check out jquery function inArray():
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: why did i get a down vote? i stated a possibility you only use it if you want. It is a correct anwser

Comment: I didn't downvote, but suggesting one use jQuery when there are extremely simple [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) solutions to the problem is like using a sledgehammer to lightly tap a nail so you can hang a painting.

Comment: You stated a solution with indexOf that is not implemented for arrays in IE<9. This is a simple cross/browser solution. I don't think jquery is solution to everything but to some simple things i rather have a cross/browser guaranteed solution...

Comment: My solution includes a simple fallback for browsers where `haystack.indexOf` doesn't exist.